# Not able to connect remote MongoDB with node nestjs app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, database-connection

Not able to connect to remote MongoDB using SRV connection string.

```
mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.*****.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I can connect same using MongoDB Compass.

Kindly help!

Comment: Cross check if you are using default port or different port.

Comment: Checked, using default port

Answer (score 0):

try to add `&directConnection=true&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1`

change `authMechanism` if you use the other mechanism

Comment: It didn't worked.

Comment: do you provide your Network Access?